# How to install mit-scheme in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, lisp

It seems to be available [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mit-scheme/).

But when I try the following command:

```
$ sudo pacman -S mit-scheme
```

I get the following:

```
error: target not found: mit-scheme
```

I've also tried with `mit-scheme-git` (from [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mit-scheme-git/)), since that seems more recently updated, but I got the same result.

Is there some other package I should be installing? Or do I need to do it without using the package manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update 1/28/19:

The package has been added to the community repository of Arch. It lives [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=mit-scheme). It can be installed with a simple `sudo pacman -S mit-scheme`.

---

## Original answer

That package doesn't seem to be available in any of the default repositories.

To install it navigate to the AUR page (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mit-scheme/) and click "Download Snapshot".

Once you have the tar of the snapshot untar it.

```
tar -xf yourfile.tar
```

Then run the command makepkg on the PKGBUILD located within the extracted archive.

```
makepkg PKGBUILD
```

That should leave you with a pkg that you can install using the

```
pacman -U pkg-goes-here.pkg command.
```

Yaourt is also a good way to download software not available in a repository.

Comment: Adding specific links would be helpful here.

Comment: This is definitely out of date. The package exists in the community repo. https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=mit-scheme

Comment: The edit is out of date again, now `mit-scheme` is back to AUR and thus the original answer is more correct.